# How do I make the HTML page content in my iFrame display at the 100% full width?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a webpage that needs to hold an iFrame with a source page of basic HTML text at the full page width.  I have set both the iFrame width and the source page body style width to 100%, but the source page still displays at about half the  of the page width.  I have event tried setting the widths to specific pixels sizes (ie. 900px), same results.

Here is a link to my page problem: http://ibew1579.org/NewSite-2017/callout.html

Here is a link to the source page and how I want the content to flow: http://ibew1579.org/NewSite-2017/updates/DailyCalls.html

Having a scroll bar for the content height is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe has a max-width: 410px; property in it. So width: 100%; will only make it 410px wide. That has to be changed or removed so the iframe can change.